# Stripes: In jsp page html table pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, stripes

I'm using stripes java framework. I have jsp page:

```
<table id="mlTable" style="">
    <col width="200">
    <col width="250">
    <thead> 
        <tr>
            <th align="center"><p>Name</p></th>
    <th align="center"><p>Address</p></th>
    </tr>
    </thead> 
    <c:forEach items="${actionBean.mLocations}" var="ml">
        <tr>
            <td><p>${ml.name}</p></td>
            <td><p>${ml.address}</p></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>

</table>
```

In my actionbean I'm returning list:

```
public List<Location> getmLocations() {
        mLocations = wrapperBean.getLocations();
    return mLocations;
}
```

What I want is pagination because list is very long. And pagination must be asynchronous without reloading the page. Because I have also search field and that value must stay in field. And I don't want use DISPLAYTAG because I'm adding some custom classes to table. What can I do? please help

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Javascript library such as [List.js](http://www.listjs.com/examples/pagination) to paginate a HTML table client-side. This avoids refreshing the page, but if the amount of data is truly staggering, it may cause performance issues, since you're always downloading the whole thing (but only once per loading the page itself).